# Mount old MS-DOS .img on Linux

Tags: disk-image, img

Is there a way to mount an old .img file that's most likely a copy of a CD-ROM made for MS-DOS on Linux? All attempts have failed yet. `file` sees it just as "data", `fdisk -l` only says

```
646,75 MiB, 678163456 bytes, 1324538 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Mounting with either `mount -o` loop and `mount -o loop,offset=512` fails. I can mount it with losetup to any /dev/loop-device, but I can't mount that anywhere. for mount I get the output

```
wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
```

and dmseg tells me

```
[39452.042543] loop0: detected capacity change from 0 to 1324537
[39452.051688] EXT4-fs (loop0): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[39452.051889] EXT4-fs (loop0): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[39452.051986] EXT4-fs (loop0): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[39452.052096] FAT-fs (loop0): bogus number of reserved sectors
[39452.052100] FAT-fs (loop0): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
```

The first lines of the hexdump are:

```
00000000  00 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  ff ff ff 00 00 02 00 01  |................|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
```

What can I do to access the content?

Comment: How would you do that?  MS -DOS (I have such a VM) is 16-bit and modern Linux is 64-bit.

Comment: @John, why not make that an answer: VM

Comment: I did so - Thank you

Comment: Try using the `file` command to see if it detects anything or use a hex editor to look inside. // Because CDs/DVDs do not have partitions, `fdisk` cannot work with them.

Comment: @DanielB Already in the question: `file` sees it just as "data".

Comment: Ah, I missed that. Using a hex editor to manually examine the contents is the only option then.

Comment: `mount`, without arguments, ought to mount an ISO9660 image correctly, or used to. Try `-t iso9660`?  Otherwise I have a suspicion it might not be an ISO9660 CD. Possibly some other weird format from Apple or Commodore?

Comment: Could you please upload the file (or only the first megabyte or so of it) somewhere, so it would be easier to identify what it is? It might be a BIN image with missing CUE (possibly a PS1 game?) or some other weird format.

Comment: @TobiaTesan also throws errors. It might be some kind of raw image as I can read some text from the hexdump, even though it's quite garbled.

Comment: @tpimh you can find the first 50 lines from hexdump here: https://pastes.io/jmwdatagnb

Comment: Bad news, judging from the header that's in all likelihood a MDF file, i.e. a proprietary format used by Alcohol 120%: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Descriptor_File

You probably want to convert it to ISO first using e.g. http://www.mdftoiso.com

Comment: @TobiaTesan thanks a lot for that analysis. I even found a Linux tool to do the conversion. Maybe you can add a comment explaining how you found that out, so others stumbling upon old img they don't know how to handle can take a look for themselves.

Comment: Er, I googled the first 32 bytes (`00 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  ff ff ff 00 00 02 00 01`) of your dump. I wish I had a more glamorous explanation :-D

Comment: It's usually the simplest things you don't think of lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My file was in the Alcohol 120% proprietary format called [MDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Descriptor_File).

I found the tool [mdf2iso](http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/m/mdf2iso/) (native Linux CLI tool) to convert the image into an ISO and I could afterwards mount it.

Comment: My pleasure. For future reference, this tool might be useful (it was one of the top hits when googling bytes from your header) https://github.com/rocketRobin/myrmec

Comment: Hi Richard, comments are often deleted. So, please add a link to the software in your answer to enhance it.

Comment: @RohitGupta I will not add links to software I've never used. That program may be installable on Linux but I've yet to find a way worth the effort.

Comment: It's in Debian stable, I think it's safe to link :-)

Comment: I thought you meant Myrmec